# Idempotent elements in any ring R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to check this: if $e_1$, $e_2$ are idempotent elements in a ring $R$, then $Re_1=Re_2$ if and only if $e_1=e_2$.

Comment: is that true for any idempotent e in a ring R, ann(e)=R(1-e)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample. Let 
$$
R=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cr
0 & \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then there exist idempotents $e,f\in R$ with $Re=Rf$ but $eR\neq fR$, see Wisbauer's *Foundations of Module and Ring Theory*, Exercises $2.14$, number $11$. In general, $eR=fR$ is equivalent to $ef=f$ and $fe=e$.

Comment: Nice example! Is there also a commutative one or does the claim hold in commutative rings?

Comment: If $R$ is commutative, then it follows $f=ef=fe=e$ from the last line.

Comment: Note that the same result holds in a monoid. If $M$ is a monoid and $e$ and $f$ are idempotents of $M$, then $eM = fM$ iff $ef = f$ and $fe = e$. Similarly $Me = Mf$ iff $fe = f$ and $ef = e$.